# Fixed length datafile, preview the result before BULK INSERT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I'm trying to bulk insert several fixed length data files. I've created the database tables and the formatfiles. Then I try the following. For example I have a format file like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RECORD>
        <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="4"/>
        <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="1"/>
        <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="20"/>
        <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="50"/>
        <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
        <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="4"/>
        <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
        <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
        <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
        <FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="1"/>
        <FIELD ID="11" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
        <FIELD ID="12" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
        <FIELD ID="13" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
        <FIELD ID="14" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
        <FIELD ID="15" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
    </RECORD>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="BSTNUM" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="4"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="MUTKOD" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="1"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="MDBST" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="20"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="MDOBST" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="50"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="MDBCOD" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="8"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="MDRECL" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="4"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="MDDATI" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="8"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="MDDATW" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="8"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="MDDATU" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="8"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="MDSTAT" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="1"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="11" NAME="MDANM0" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="8"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="12" NAME="MDANM1" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="8"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="13" NAME="MDANM2" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="8"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="14" NAME="MDANM3" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="8"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="15" NAME="MDANTL" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="8"/>
    </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

And then in the SQL Server 2008 command prompt I try this:

```
BULK INSERT
    BST012018_testtable
from
    'D:\testimport\BST012018T.txt'
WITH (
    FORMATFILE='D:\testimport\BST012018T_format.xml',
    ROWS_PER_BATCH = 1000,
    KEEPNULLS
)
```

and get an error message:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

The error can be in the datafile, the fixed length format file, or the datatype/columns in the database table. In other words, for this to work these 3 things (table, datafile, formatfile) must be perfectly aligned.

The dataset I'm working on has more files like this, and some of them have 50+ columns and >100.000 records. So figuring out where the error occured requires adjusting the formatfile, maybe adjusting the tables, trial and error etc.

So my question is, is it possible to preview the BULK INSERT somehow? Do a `SELECT` from the fixed length data+formatfile instead of just inserting directly? Or put another way, how can I preview the data in the way SQL Server would interpret it from this type of `BULK INSERT` command?

Comment: Use SSIS instead?

Comment: Welcome to the nightmare of ETLs.

Comment: [`SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-bulk-data-by-using-bulk-insert-or-openrowset-bulk-sql-server) allows you to select the data first, but isn't going to give you clearer error messages on a mismatch. You can use things like `SINGLE_NCLOB` to read the whole file as a string for inspection, though (or use a trivial format file that reads whole lines as rows with one `NVARCHAR(MAX)` columns for easy inspection of rows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to answer my own question. Thanks to comment by Jeroen Mostert, using the `OPENROWSET(BULK..` to select from a datafile is what I was looking for.

You can select the TOP 10 or something like that to only view the first few records and inspect for any mistakes. Btw the datafile and formatfile must placed in a folder on the server, SQL Server can't just read your local pc.

```
SELECT
    TOP 5 *
FROM 
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'D:\testimport\BST012018T.txt',
        FORMATFILE = 'D:\testimport\BST012018T_format.xml'
        --,CODEPAGE = '65001' -- 65001 = UTF-8 supported in SQL Server 2016
    ) AS a
```

Seeing a preview of the resulting dataset like this, I could figure out that there was a missing column at the end and also no row terminator (in my case Cr Lf) in the format file. In the RECORD part, I added a last field with type "CharTerm" with attribute TERMINATOR, so something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RECORD>
        <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="4"/>
        <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="1"/>
        <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="20"/>
        <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="50"/>
        <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
        <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="4"/>
        <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
        <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
        <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
        <FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="1"/>
        <FIELD ID="11" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
        <FIELD ID="12" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
        <FIELD ID="13" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
        <FIELD ID="14" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
        <FIELD ID="15" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
        <FIELD ID="16" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
        <FIELD ID="17" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n"/>
    </RECORD>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="BSTNUM" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="MUTKOD" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="MDBST" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="MDOBST" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="MDBCOD" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="MDRECL" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="MDDATI" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="MDDATW" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="MDDATU" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="MDSTAT" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="11" NAME="MDANM0" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="12" NAME="MDANM1" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="13" NAME="MDANM2" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="14" NAME="MDANM3" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="15" NAME="MDANTL" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="16" NAME="EMPTY" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
    </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```